# Dispatcher error with mongrel rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am using Ruby 1.9.3, Rails 3.2.3 and mongrel. I did scaffolding to create project model.
Then I opened index page of project, it is showing blank page. When I see log there is some dispatcher error as shown below:

```
** Signals ready.  TERM => stop.  USR2 => restart.  INT => stop (no restart).
** Rails signals registered.  HUP => reload (without restart).  It might not work well.
** Mongrel 1.2.0.pre2 available at 0.0.0.0:3000
** Use CTRL-C to stop.
2012-10-20 23:57:52 +0530: Error calling Dispatcher.dispatch #<NameError: uninitialized constant ActionController::CgiRequest>
/home/username/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p286/gems/mongrel-1.2.0.pre2/lib/mongrel/rails.rb:76:in `block in process'
<internal:prelude>:10:in `synchronize'
/home/username/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p286/gems/mongrel-1.2.0.pre2/lib/mongrel/rails.rb:74:in `process'
/home/username/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p286/gems/mongrel-1.2.0.pre2/lib/mongrel.rb:165:in `block in process_client'
/home/username/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p286/gems/mongrel-1.2.0.pre2/lib/mongrel.rb:164:in `each'
/home/username/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p286/gems/mongrel-1.2.0.pre2/lib/mongrel.rb:164:in `process_client'
/home/username/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p286/gems/mongrel-1.2.0.pre2/lib/mongrel.rb:291:in `block (2 levels) in run'
2012-10-20 23:58:10 +0530: Error calling Dispatcher.dispatch #<NameError: uninitialized constant ActionController::CgiRequest>
/home/username/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p286/gems/mongrel-1.2.0.pre2/lib/mongrel/rails.rb:76:in `block in process'
```

Comment: Your mongrel version seems to be quite old. 1.8.0 is the most recent version. https://github.com/zedshaw/mongrel2